# Does a computer dying (battery dead) close its incognito tabs

Tags: browser, private-browsing

Does incognito tabs on a computer with no battery stay after turning on again?

Comment: It sounds like this would not be difficult to test. What research have you done and what have you tried to try to find an answer for this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

if the browser process was terminated (closed successfully), which a computer being shutdown due to a dead battery would no doubt do, there should be no reason for any incognito tabs to re-open. that goes against the core functionality of the browser's implementation. there may be some instances where a dedicated private browser window is re-opened, but it will just be blank and show no previous activities.

Comment: I am pretty sure incognito can be configured to restore the same sesson.  It just defeats the purpose of it.  I would also like to point out that incognito mode doesn't mean privacy mode, by default the session won't be restored, which means any open tabs must be reopened.  Google, Facebook, and others tracking will still be used while the browser is opened.